# Are chained QuerySet filters equivalent to defining multiple fields in a single filter with the Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, filtering

When filtering a queryset, I'm wondering if the following are equivalent.

```
User.objects.filter(username='josh').filter(email__startswith='josh')
User.objects.filter(username='josh', email__startswith='josh')
```

I can't imagine how the generated SQL could be any different between the two. The documentation doesn't seem to mention any differences either.

Comment: But you get different results?

Comment: No examples that I can come up with, currently, return different results. But I seem to remember there was a difference at some point, and just recently remembered I wanted to track down if there is a difference. I'm asking in the general sense, without a specific example.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute those queries in the shell and print out the generated SQL like:

```
>>> print User.objects.filter(username='josh').filter(email__startswith='josh').query
```

I tested a similiar queries like you got here and there was no difference in the generated SQL code.Both statements end up using them same WHERE Statement.

Furhtermore it shouldnt make any difference in this case whether you chain the filters or apply them in one step.

But there are scenarios in which the order of filtering matters.
Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

Comment: No difference, just confirmed although I believe it should not. Could also check actual SQL by django.db.connection.queries, but `.query()` is always easier.

Comment: @okm, I've used .query to check some of the simple queries and there is no difference. But as Jingo points out, apparently the order of which you apply filtering on relationships that span has an impact. The documentation is somewhat confusing though.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton yes, you could update the question about confusing part. For spanned lookup, each filter/exclude appends join seperatly, then the generated query is subject to the actual ordering and lookup fields.

Comment: @okm, but is the effect due to the ordering only, or the use of multiple kwargs within a single `filter` compared to chained filters?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton I think mainly the latter w/ spanned lookup. The ordering may change the WHERE condition in the generated SQL, but not definitely change the results; the spanned lookups, in separated filters, always introduce extra join and thus change the result.

Answer (score 0):

Django QuerySets are lazy, running:

```
User.objects.filter(username='josh').filter(email__startswith='josh')
```

or even

```
a = User.objects.filter(username='josh')
a = a.filter(email__startswith='josh')
```

produces only a single db query, that is performed when you try to access your data. Such query agreegates all filters and excludes in the where clause.

Comment: I know they are lazy. I'm trying to discuss the difference (if one exists) between using multiple `filters` or a single `filter` with multiple kwargs.