# Django conditional count

Tags: mysql, django, annotations

I am querying the names of all the Tags that I've flagged as "visible":

```
visible_tags = Tag.objects.filter(visible=True,taggit_taggeditem_items__content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Action)).order_by('name')
```

I want to add a field called "action_count" that tells me how many actions are associated with this tag:

```
visible_tags = Tag.objects.filter(visible=True,taggit_taggeditem_items__content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Action)).order_by('name').annotate(action_count=Count('action'))
```

This works except that I want to know not just now many actions are affiliated, but how many actions that are *incomplete* that are affiliated with this tag.

I tried the following:

```
visible_tags = Tag.objects.filter(visible=True,taggit_taggeditem_items__content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Action)).order_by('name').filter(action__complete=False).annotate(action_count=Count('action'))
```

But this doesn't quite do what I need it to do.  **How can I annotate the count of actions that are incomplete?**

Comment: That looks like it should work. What does it give you and how does it differ from your expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get more count than expected. This is because chained `.filter` that introduce extra inner join, very similar to the question [Are chained QuerySet filters equivalent to defining multiple fields in a single filter with the Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072605/are-chained-queryset-filters-equivalent-to-defining-multiple-fields-in-a-single)
Thus put the second filter in the first one:

```
visible_tags = Tag.objects.filter(visible=True, taggit_taggeditem_items__content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Action), 
action__complete=False # Here
).order_by('name').annotate(action_count=Count('action'))
```

Besides, `print queryset.query` to know what SQL Django generates for you.